# Remove blank rows CSV - Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have this piece of code :

```
function Get-SWList { 
        try { Get-WmiObject Win32_Product -ComputerName $PCname -ErrorAction "Stop" | Select-Object Name,Version |Export-Csv $logLocation${PCname}.csv -NoTypeInformation }
        catch {}
        finally { $logDate |Out-file -Append "$logLocation${PCname}.csv"}
}
```

Output example:

[image: Table example]

I cannot figure the code out to remove blank rows of data.

I'm trying to remove blank rows of data

Comment: Put a `| Where-Object {![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.Name)}` before piping to the Select-Object cmdlet

Comment: @theo is this different to ```?{$_.name}``` - probably the whiteSpace part?

Comment: @Tony Yes, I used `IsNullOrWhitespace` because the string could be just a bunch of spaces, tabs etc. That is also why the OPs own answer can fail.

Answer (score 0):

I added `Where-Object  {$_.Name.Length -gt 0 }`   and it now works. Thank you